# Oracle Bulk Insert Using SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have recently taken data dumps from an Oracle database.
Many of them are large in size(~5GB). I am trying to insert the dumped data into another Oracle database by executing the following SQL in SQL Developer

```
@C:\path\to\table_dump1.sql;
@C:\path\to\table_dump2.sql;
@C:\path\to\table_dump3.sql;
             :
```

but it is taking a long time like more than a day to complete even a single SQL file.
Is there any better way to get this done faster?

Comment: What kind of dump do you have? are these files a list of insert statements or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

SQL*Loader is my favorite way to bulk load large data volumes into Oracle.  Use the direct path insert option for max speed but understand impacts of direct-path loads (for example, all data is inserted past the high water mark, which is fine if you truncate your table).  It even has a tolerance for bad rows, so if your data has "some" mistakes it can still work.

SQL*Loader can suspend indexes and build them all at the end, which makes bulk inserting very fast.

Example of a SQL*Loader call:

```
$SQLDIR/sqlldr /@MyDatabase direct=false silent=feedback \
    control=mydata.ctl log=/apps/logs/mydata.log bad=/apps/logs/mydata.bad \
    rows=200000
```

And the mydata.ctl would look something like this:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE '/apps/load_files/mytable.dat'
INTO TABLE my_schema.my_able
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|"
 (ORDER_ID,
  ORDER_DATE,
  PART_NUMBER,
  QUANTITY)
```

Alternatively...  if you are just copying the entire contents of one table to another, across databases, you can do this if your DBA sets up a DBlink (a 30 second process), presupposing your DB is set up with the redo space to accomplish this.

```
truncate table my_schema.my_table;

insert into my_schema.my_table
select * from my_schema.my_table@my_remote_db;
```

The use of the `/* +append */` hint can still make use of direct path insert.

Comment: My dump files are just millions of lines of insert SQL statements. Can I still use SQL Loader to load the data?

Comment: No, not exactly...  instead of insert statements, you want to change the files to be either fixed-width or delimited files.  What is the origin of the data?  My guess would be it's easier to extract it as a data file than a series of SQL statements...  If not, you could script the SQL into a data file (using Perl, for example)

Comment: All I have are files that contains millions of insert statements. I guess I should convert them into csv format or something as you suggested.

Comment: Where did these SQL inserts come from?  It seems to me if you hijack that source, you can change the output to whatever you want